# Как определить метод для делегата автоматически?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Если заголовок не понятен, то объясню другими словами. Есть, например `ExecutedRoutedEventHandler`. Как мне быстро получить из него

```
void FirstPageCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

? Короче как можно быстро раскрыть хандлер в функцию в коде? Напечатал я такой `ExecutedRoutedEventHandler +=`, чего нибудь нажал, а функция бы создалась сама. Может есть горячие клавиши для этого? А то приходится возвращаться к хандлеру, наводить на него, чтобы посмотреть типы параметров.

Comment: Поставьте R# и будет Вам счастье

Comment: @ixSci, не будет счастья. Он вешает мне студию. Можно, конечно, посидеть, настроить, отключить все лишнее.... Но не тратить же время из за одной функции. А средства студии этого не позволяют сделать?

Comment: Не знаю про средства студии, т.к. стоит решарпер и я не знаю что даёт студия, а что сам решарпер.

Comment: А два раза Tab после += пробовали?

Comment: @VladD, спасибо!

Comment: @iRumba: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Пишете `ExecutedRoutedEventHandler +=`, потом нажимаете <kbd>Tab</kbd> -- добавляется название сгенеренного метода, потом еще раз <kbd>Tab</kbd> -- генерится сам метод.

Comment: Ага, помогло! Спасибо!

Comment: @iRumba не за что!